# Spring Boot : Tomcat illegel access exception

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat, model-view-controller

I'm trying to run a web application in Eclipse, but tomcat is showing this illegal access exception:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1004)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Eclipse mars version, tomcat 8, java 8, spring 5 and hibernate 5.